# How to add custom java object to HashTable

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

I have class called Items with some data as below:

```
class Items {
    public String item1 ;
    public String item2;
    public int item3;
}
```

I have another Java class that sets values for this Items class as below:

```
Items tempItems1 = new Items();
tempItems1 .item1  = "a";
tempItems1 .item2  = "b";
tempItems1 .item3  = 1;

Items tempItems2 = new Items();
tempItems2 .item1  = "aa";
tempItems2 .item2  = "bb";
tempItems2 .item3  = 11;
```

Now the problem is I need to add these both objects (tempItems1,tempItems2) to HashTable in such a way I can traverse through the HashTable to get values for this.

I created HashTable as below, but not able to find a way in which I can add each of the above Java object and traverse through it.

```
HashTable<String,Items> custom = new HashTable<String,Items>();
```

Can any one  help me in sorting out this issue ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html or you could ... read the Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: `custom.put("someString", items1);` ?

Comment: You speak about traversing the `HashMap` but you are not talking about any key used to retrieve the data. Are you sure you need a `Map`? maybe you need a `Set`? or a normal `List`?

Comment: I need a map to traverse

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
custom.put("string_key1", tempItems1);
custom.put("string_key2", tempItems2);
```

Traverse

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Items> entry : custom.entrySet()) {
    // entry.getKey()
    // entry.getValue()
}
```

Comment: Hi , I need to traverse in such a way that  I need to give key to get the val as below:                                                     entry.getKey I should get as item1 and entry.getvalue() to get its value as "a"

Comment: @user1276092 It seems you have problem with Java itself. If you have `Items` object , you can't access member variables by key; make them private and use getters instead. It's not a HashAnything, just a regular object